# Windows Bash Scripting: get most recent file with specific file name as T'yyyymmddhhmm'ABCDEF.csv

Tags: windows, batch

I need to copy a file called: T'yyyymmddhhmm'ABCDEF.csv to another drive, where the hhmm need to be ignored and it is not a fixed time csv output

I found some information as below script, but have no idea how to setup the filename, because the source path contains other files, likes: T'yyyymmddhhmm'ZZZZZZ.csv

```
setlocal
set srcDir=\\sql1\Backups\Avidian
set destdir=E:\2014_Backups
set lastmod=
pushd %srcDir%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *.bak /b /o-d /a-d 2^>NUL') do set lastmod=%%a & goto :xx
:xx
if "%lastmod%"=="" echo Could not locate files.&goto :eof
:::
copy "%lastmod%" "%destDir%"
```

Thanks all